# Python Selenium - Detect firefox geolocation alert popup

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Selenium provides option to allow or deny geolocation access with the help of below config

```
1. geo.enabled
2. geo.prompt.testing
3. geo.prompt.testing.allow
```

but before allowing or denying location access I want to check whether alert pop up is coming or not. Is there a way?

Its not a normal alert pop up wherein I can use switch `driver.switchTo().alert()` method in try catch block to detect its presence.

Thought of taking screenshot of page and then use OCR to extract text but screenshot also doesn't capture that alert

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: does the alert popup always look the same? if yes, then you can use pyautogui to check if popup is present or not

Comment: In headless mode it will be a challenge then.

Comment: in headless pyautogui doesn't work